# Alocação estoura memória em função recursiva em C

Tags: c, recursão, gerenciamento-de-memória

Criei um programa que fica alocando de 4 em 4 bytes de memória sucessivamente através de uma função recursiva:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BUF 2

void overflow(int payload){
    payload = payload - 1;
    int stack = (int)malloc(payload * sizeof(int));
    payload = payload + 1;
    overflow(payload);
}


int main(void){
    overflow(BUF);
    return 0;
}
```

Acontece que ele para de funcionar antes de conseguir consumir toda a memoria isto seria algum tipo de controle do própio Windows para garantir a integridade do sistema ou é erro de programação mesmo?

Como eu poderia contornar isso e deixa o programa consumindo memoria até o topo e quando chegar ao topo parar de alocar memoria?

Estou usando windows 7 64 bits

Comment: Parar de funcionar você quer dizer que ele fecha sozinho? Aparece alguma mensagem se executar via CMD?

Comment: sim, ele so consegue alocar ate uns 90% da memoria e para

Comment: Tá, mas vc só respondeu "sim" ... Eu fiz **duas** perguntas, eu não sei se o sim foi pra primeira ou pra segunda. Então ele fecha sozinho? Sim ou não? Tentou rodar o teu programa chamando/compilando via CMD? Por exemplo: `c:\Users\projeto>g++ meu.cpp -o meu.exe && meu.exe`. Se tentou que mensagem de erro aparece no momento que ele finaliza?

Comment: não me retorna nenhum erro na compilação esse codigo esta funcional me parece que algo relacionado a linguagem mesmo estrutura de dados alocação dinamica e tal ele executa normal mas quando chega nos 90% para de alocar memoria e o windows cancela a execução do programa

Comment: Tem antivirus no teu PC?

Comment: Acredito que o seu problema pode ser estouro de pilha, devido a várias recursões envolvidas. Me parece que o tamanho padrão é de 1 Mbytes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686774(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Aqui deu este problema: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iolXN.png

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não tem antivirus só o windows defender que esta ativado

Comment: acho que o problema estava na recursão mesmo eu coloquei dentro de um while e funcionou

Comment: Está usando qual versão do mingw? Pra eu poder testar.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento 6.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É erro de programação e estouro da pilha porque a recursão não tem fim. Se mudou para um laço e funcionou, é porque o laço tem uma condição que o encerra, caso contrário não teria fim, ainda que não haveria estouro de pilha. Mas em algum momento longínquo estouraria o *heap* também.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BUF 2

void *overflow(int payload) {
    if (--payload) {
        int *stack = malloc(payload * sizeof(int));
        overflow(payload);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    overflow(BUF);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/8AShM8). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hevewper-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Recursion.c).

Comment: por que você colocou no retorno da função void um ponteiro e declarou um ponteiro na variável stack? não entendi.

Comment: @Assanges não lembro porque coloquei no retorno, eu acho que foi sem querer, não tem necessidade não. `malloc()` retorna um ponteiro, então a variável que vai receber tem que ser um ponteiro. Tem compilador que aceita um ponteiro ser jogado em um inteiro, mas isso não costuma ser adequado.

Answer (score 0):

Tente com o seguinte código, retirado de [uma resposta no StackOverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798330/maximum-memory-which-malloc-can-allocate):

```
main() {
  int Mb = 0;
  while ( malloc(1<<20)) ++Mb;
  printf("Allocated %d Mb total\n", Mb);
}
```

(Declare stdio e stdlib para este exemplo)

Comment: Infelizmente, acredito que não responde a pergunta o post.

Comment: eu fiz dentro de um while e funcionou como o esperado travou minha maquina precisei reiniciar executem por conta e risco 
`#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    while(1){
        int stack = (int)malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
    }
    return 0;
}
`